# Segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: segmentation-fault, assembler

GNU as compiler shows this error while running my executable ./hello which I get as a result of the proper compilation.
The output is unexpected.
Pls help using wsl for windows

Comment: I have changed the assembler to NASM.Now I get the output, but the segmentation fault still exists with it.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code does not have any errors in it, this is the common cause of the Segmentation Fault error. You should ask any questions related to code on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)